# Magento theme link between the header block and the topSearch (catelogsearch/form.mini.phtml)

Tags: php, magento, header, themes

I start learning how to create a Magento theme. I start to understand what blocks are and where to find a specific phtml file by setting ***Template Path Hints*** and ***Add Block Names to Hints*** to Yes. Below is the ***header*** block inside the ***layout/page.xml*** file.

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
            <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
            <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
                <label>Page Header</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="page/html_welcome" name="welcome" as="welcome"/>
</block>
```

With the above XML block, it loads the ***template/page/html/header.phtml*** file. The code below lives in the ***header.phtml***.

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
```

With this ***$this->getChildHtml('topSearch')*** method, I expect it will find the ***topSearch*** block inside the ***header*** block in the ***page.xml*** file and load its phtml file. But there is no topSearch block living in the header block inside the page.xml. The fact is that it loads the ***topSearch*** block from the ***layout/catelogsearch.xml***. My question is how does it know it needs to load the ***topSearch*** block from the ***layout/catelogsearch.xml*** instead?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that Magento will merge together all layout files into one during run-time makes this possible. So it won't actually look for `topSearch` reference because it doesn't have to. After the merge is done `topSearch` will become a child block of `page/html_header` block.

```
<default> <!--page handle, <default> is used on all pages-->
    <reference name="header"> <!--reference to page/html_header block-->
        <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

Recommended read:
[Intro to Layouts](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts)
[Magento for Developers: Part 4 - Magento Layouts, Blocks and Templates](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates)